# TypeScript generates all files in root of outDir

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

Typescript 2.3.3 within VS 2015

Have a project which contains TSSrc/Subfolder1 and plenty .ts files there.

Have a flowing tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": false, 
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "../Scripts/TSOutput"
  },
  "files": [
    "Subfolder1/file1.ts",
    "Subfolder1/file2.ts",
    "Subfolder1/file3.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true

}
```

My problem is that TypeScript generates all .js file directly in outDir but not outDir/Subfolder1, how to force it always use appropriate subfolder hierarchy?

So far the only solution I've found is to create extra fake .ts file in different source subfolder

```
"files": [
        "Subfolder2/stub.ts",
        "Subfolder1/file1.ts",
        "Subfolder1/file2.ts",
        "Subfolder1/file3.ts"
      ]
```

After this workaround TS generates Subfolder1 and Subfolder2 inside of outDir and puts js files there. - which is kind of OK solution and even may save someone's time, unless there is a correct way to do so. Please help if you know how to.

Comment: change `"outDir": "../Scripts/TSOutput"` to  `"outDir": "../Scripts/TSOutput/Subfolder1"` or else use `rootDir`

Comment: Try to put all of the source files/directories under a parent directory, let's say "src" and then try using `"rootDir": "src"` instead of `files`

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear, but I need TS to put output files to Subfolder1 or Subfolder2 depending on where .ts file was located in Src folder, so changing outDir to /Scripts/TSOutput/Subfolder1 would not help me.

Comment: Moved all subfolders to Logic folder and tried "rootDirs": [ "./Logic" ] - didn't help - all output files are going to outDir root.
**But when i tried "rootDir": "./Logic"  - it worked, now Subfolder1 generated in outDir and files went there.**

**Thank you!** it much nicer solution then fake .ts file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tiona points out, you should probably be using a combination of `outDir` and `rootDir`. Please take a look at [this TypeScript GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5134), which is about the same issue you are experiencing. Your tsconfig file should look something like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": false, 
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "../Scripts/TSOutput",
    "rootDir": "./"
  },
  "files": [
    "Src/Subfolder1/file1.ts",
    "Src/Subfolder1/file2.ts",
    "Src/Subfolder1/file3.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Edited based on your comment above.

If your TS files are in folders under a `Src` folder, and you want the JS files in the TSOutput folder under the same subfolders, the above tsconfig should work.

This will put `Src/Subfolder1/file1.ts` output into `../Scripts/TSOutput/Subfolder1/file1.js`